# System for user reports of certain incidents

Tags: web-apps, cms

I am planning a site similar in function to [IPaidABribe.com](http://IPaidABribe.com), where users can (anonymously) report certain incidents within their work-life.

Each report is linked to a company and possibly a division therein. Reports can be made anonymously or with a Google/Facebook/Whatever ID. The goal is to collect data that allows to inform (company) policy.

Ideally the database of companies/division can be maintained in a wiki-style by users, but that's not crucial. The solution should be run as a web-service.

Does a system like this exist, i.e. some form of Wiki/CMS software that could be used for this? Or would I have to start from scratch?

I would prefer open source solutions. Free is great, but in principle there would be the option of allocating a small budget, however I'm *not* asking for someone to code this up for me. Ideally the solution would be scaleable, I'd start it on a personal web-server and do not expect many users simultaneously.

The server is not yet in place, so could be windows or linux. Software that "almost does what I want" is also fine. I'm happy to tweak any python/php/perl code to suit my purposes.